# Graphic-Card getting disabled while playing

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have a strange problem: When I play games (StarCraft, Titanfall, CSGO), it can happen that the graphics card "logs out" of Windows. You can hear the typical sound like you would remove a USB stick. The screen then turns black and you have no chance to get a signal back. The system does not freeze or crash, you can hear the game continue running normally and I can continue to use Skype or Teamspeak. I am unable to reproduce the error. It just seems random. Sometimes I can play for hours, sometimes it happend 5 minutes in a row.

My rig: MSI GTX 970, Intel i7 4790, GSkill 16 GB RAM, Samsung 840 1TB SSD

Operation System: Windows 10 Pro (Version: 1709, Build: 16299.309)
Driver: 391.24

What i did so far:

- removed graphic driver and installed newest one
- temperature is fine: IDLE 38C°, Load: ~60°C
- diffrent monitor with an other cable (DVI), but same issue
- dxdiag says no problems but found this entry there:

  Problemsignatur:
  P1: SC2_x64.exe
  P2: 4.2.1.62848
  P3: 10.0.16299.2.0.0
  P4: 
  P5: 
  P6: 
  P7: 
  P8: 
  P9: 
  P10:

  Angefügte Dateien:
  \?\C:\Users\skull3r7\AppData\Local\Temp\RDR54C.tmp\empty.txt
  \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER54D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER56B.tmp.csv
  \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER58B.tmp.txt

  Diese Dateien befinden sich möglicherweise hier:

  Analysesymbol: 
  Es wird erneut nach einer Lösung gesucht: 0
  Berichts-ID: 1544043d-846e-49d0-beb8-a53411350216
  Berichtstatus: 268435456
  Bucket mit Hash: cbfc3f11ed9e6d3cde213d550717ba2a
  +++ WER7 +++:
  Fehlerbucket 2280820502577011345, Typ 5
  Ereignisname: MoBEX
  Antwort: Nicht verfügbar
  CAB-Datei-ID: 0
- deleted and installed Windows with fresh drivers

Comment: I think it's more likely that's the monitor to disconnect, not the graphics card. Otherwise the game would not continue running

Comment: I tried a diffrent monitor with an other cable (DVI), but same issue. Good hint.

Comment: Have you checked your event viewer for VPU recovery or Timeout Detection & Recovery events?